# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file even after giving second arg for open()

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlsxwriter

I am trying to run this code:

```
import xlrd
import os.path
import xlsxwriter

with open("arrays.xlsx", "a") as my_file:
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(my_file)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    row = 0
    for col, data in enumerate(array):
        worksheet.write_column(row, 0, array)

workbook.close()
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1649, in __del__
self.close()
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1666, in close
self.fp.seek(self.start_dir)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to append to an xlsx file with XlsxWriter. However you can't append to a binary Excel file and XlsxWriter doesn't support rewriting files. Try OpenPyXL.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @e4c5  Yes Sir, it works. Thank you.

Comment: Okay sure, Sir. I was unaware of this. Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) you don't actually need to close the file.

> The `with` statement is used to wrap the execution of a block with
>   methods defined by a context manager (see section [With Statement
>   Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers)). This allows common [`try...except...finally`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#except) usage
>   patterns to be encapsulated for convenient reuse.

The implicit finally block which is hidden here will close the file for you. Just remove your explicit close and you will be fine.

Comment: It shows this error Sir-
Exception: Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.

Comment: in that case what you should take out is the with block :-)

Comment: @NILESHSUTHAR: I would try moving the `workbook.close()` so it's at the end of the `with` block (as opposed to not using a `with`, which is a very good practice).